# Deserialize generic type with XStream

Tags: java, xstream, generic-type-argument

I'm trying to use XStream to deserialize a xml response to a class that has a generic type field.

For example I have class *Response*

```
class Response<T extends BaseDTO>{
    int id;
    T field;

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public T getField(){
        return field;
    }
}

class B extends BaseDTO{}

class C extends BaseDTO{}

public abstract class XStreamFactory{
    public static <T extends BaseDTO> XStream initXStream(Class<T> c){
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
        xstream.alias("response-root", Response.class);
        if(c.equals(B.class)){
            xstream.alias("specific-response-b", B.class);
        else
            xstream.alias("specific-response-c", C.class);

    xstream = addAliases(xstream, c);
    return xstream;
    }

    // we want to process the annotations declared on type c
    protected static XStream addAliases(XStream xstream, Class<?> c){       
        while (c != null) {
            xstream.processAnnotations(c);
            c = c.getSuperclass();
        }
        return xstream;
    }
}
```

To deserialize the response I do the following:

```
XStream xstream = XStreamFactory.initializeXStream(B.class);
Response<B> resp = (Response<B>) xstream.fromXML(response);
```

Below are the xml responses that I get:

```
<response-root>
    <id></id>
    <specific-response-b>
        //... content specific for class B
    </specific-response-b>
</response-root>
```

or

```
<response-root>
    <id></id>
    <specific-response-c>
        //... content specific for class c
    </specific-response-c>
</response-root>
```

The code above does not deserialize the response. It throws the following exception:

```
 com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Element specific-response-b of type B is not defined as field in type Response
```

Can you guys provide any pointers on how to achieve what I want?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

XStream doesn't have a problem with this. It's probably some kind of custom marshalling that you're doing. Here's an example of marshalling and unmarshalling the classes you specified above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Response<B> responseB = new Response<B>(5, new B());
    String xml = new XStream().toXML(responseB);
    System.out.println("marshalled:\n" + xml);
    Response<B> resultB = (Response<B>) new XStream().fromXML(xml);
    System.out.println("unmarshalled: " + resultB);

    Response<C> responseC = new Response<C>(10, new C());
    xml = new XStream().toXML(responseC);
    System.out.println("marshalled:\n" + xml);
    Response<C> resultC = (Response<C>) new XStream().fromXML(xml);
    System.out.println("unmarshalled: " + resultC);
}

static class Response<T extends Foo> {
    int id;
    T field;

    Response(int id, T field) {
        this.id = id;
        this.field = field;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public T getField() { return field; }
}

static class Foo {}

static class B extends Foo {}

static class C extends Foo {}
```

The output--a little messy because of no aliasing and no toString():

```
marshalled:
<rds.testbed.XStreamReadingNamespaceAttributes_-Response>
  <id>5</id>
  <field class="rds.testbed.XStreamReadingNamespaceAttributes$B"/>
</rds.testbed.XStreamReadingNamespaceAttributes_-Response>
unmarshalled: rds.testbed.XStreamReadingNamespaceAttributes$Response@1cc7b00c
marshalled:
<rds.testbed.XStreamReadingNamespaceAttributes_-Response>
  <id>10</id>
  <field class="rds.testbed.XStreamReadingNamespaceAttributes$C"/>
</rds.testbed.XStreamReadingNamespaceAttributes_-Response>
unmarshalled: rds.testbed.XStreamReadingNamespaceAttributes$Response@3d66aa18
```

Comment: Well, I don't know. I do not use custom marshaling. In my case I do not serialize the classes (i get the XML from a third party, and this is just plain XML), so I guess this is where the problem might be hiding.

Comment: By "custom marshaling", I mean generally setting aliases and registering converters. You have to be doing something like that, or it certainly won't work for the XML you showed.

Comment: Yeah, of course I have aliases, I will update the code to show the annotations that I use.